# Binary strings and discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Question:

> Let $S$ be the set of binary strings of length $30$ with $10$ $1$’s and $20$ $0$’s. Let $A$ be the set of the first $30$ positive integers $\{1,2,3,\dots,30\}$. Let $B$ be the set of all subsets of $A$ containing $10$ numbers. Find a one-to-one correspondence between $S$ and $B$.

I get that I have to find a one to one correspondence but I don't get how they are related in the first place. If I could have a better conceptual understanding of the problem like a picture, I could get it.

Comment: I mean.... just assign the value $1$ if an element is contained in the subset, and $0$ otherwise. Then write these elements as a single string of $0$ and $1$ in ascending order for the values from $1$ to $30$. For example $A_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11\}$ would become: $111111111010\cdots0$, another example would be $A_2=\{3,5,7,9,11,13,14,15,16,17\}$ is mapped to ad fro: $001010101010111110\cdots0$

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to start with a simpler version of the problem so that you could draw pictures, say, let $T$ be the set of all bitstrings of length $8$ with three $1$s and five $0$s, and let $C$ be $\{1,2,\dots,8\}$, and let $D$ be the set of all subsets of $C$ containing three numbers.

Now visualize an element of $C$; for example, $\{3,5,6\}$. What would the corresponding bitstring be? If we only had three $1$s, we could assign a one to each position corresponding to an element of $\{3,5,6\}$ like so:

$0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0$

Maybe even make a chart:

$1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8$

---

$0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 1\ 1\ 0\ 0$

See if you can continue from here.

Comment: Okay, I kind of get it now. But how do I construct a function for this?

Comment: You probably don't have to be overly technical. Supposing $f$ is your function that maps bitstrings to sets, you can say something like "if $b$ is a bitstring, then $x$ is an element of $f(b)$ if and only if there is a ... in the ... position", where you fill in the ellipses.

Comment: Also, a set like {28,29,30} is with the first 27 numbers being 0 and the last three being 1's right?

Comment: I still don't get how can i map S to B. Is that even possible? In my head, I don't think so or maybe I'm not seeing it.

Comment: You are right with your $\{28,29,30\}$ example. Focus on filling in the blanks in the above comment; part of the process is discovery, even if it takes a little while.

Comment: Would I write that every distinct position in T corresponds to a distinct value in B, which makes it a one-to-one correspondence? Is that enough to prove that it is one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: Okay, that's a start. You'll have to explicitly show that it's one-to-one and onto, but that shouldn't be too hard. For one-to-one, assume $f(b_1)=f(b_2)$ for some bitstrings $b_1$ and $b_2$, and then prove $b_!$ and $b_2$ must be equal. For onto, let $T \in B$ and describe the bitstring $b$ that corresponds to $T$.

Comment: Can I just provide an example because I don't know how to explicitly show that's one-to-one and onto?

Comment: That's up to whoever's grading you.

Comment: How would you explicitly show it?